# What is the regex to match the entire paragraph with a word condition? (paragraph may contain multiple periods/full stops)

Tags: python, regex, string, regex-negation, regex-greedy

String need to match : Lisa Ellis Analyst, MoffettNathanson LLC Q Hi. Good afternoon, guys, and welcome, Brian. I look forward to working with you.

**Regex Tried** :  `[^.]*Analyst[^.]*`

**Matched Output** : *Lisa Ellis Analyst, MoffettNathanson LLC Q Hi*

### As you can see above, it stops matching after the first full stop.

Could somebody tell me how should I match the entire paragraph so that it does not stop after the first period?

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match the whole para. 
`^.*Analyst.*$/m`
I think you just need to set the multiline flag.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that paragraphs are delimited by one or more newline characters, that is, the sentences comprising a paragraph have no newline characters embedded. Then, in *multiline* mode the anchors `^` and `$` match the start and end of a line respectively in addition to the start and end of the input string. You also want to ensure that the word you are looking for is on word boundaries, that is, separated on either side by non-word characters. In that way, if you are looking for `Analyst`, you will not match `Analysts`:

`\bAnalyst\b`

If you want to match either `Analyst` or `Analysts`, then make it explicit:

`\bAnalysts?\b`

If you want to match *any* word that begins with `Analyst`:

`\bAnalyst\w+\b`

The complete regex:

```
(?m)^.*?\bAnalyst\b.*?$
```

1. `(m)` Turn on multiline mode.
2. `^` Matches the start of the string or the start of a line.
3. `.*?` Matches minimally 0 or more characters until:
4. `\bAnalyst\b` Matches `Analyst` on a word boundary (use `\bAnalyst\w+\b` for any word that begins with `Analyst`).
5. `.*?$` Matches minimally 0 or more characters until the end of line or the end of string. You could use `.*`, greedy matching, because `.` will never match the newline character, so there is really no danger of matching beyond the end of the paragraph.

The code:

```
import re

text = """This is sentence 1 in paragraph 1. This is sentence 2 in paragraph 1.

This is sentence 1 in paragraph 2. This is sentence 2 in paragraph 2 with the word Analyst contained within.
"""

l = re.findall(r'(?m)^.*?\bAnalyst\b.*?$', text)
print(l)
```

Prints:

```
['This is sentence 1 in paragraph 2. This is sentence 2 in paragraph 2 with the word Analyst contained within.']
```